# Clearing messages in heartbeat Kafka topics

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, cdc, debezium-engine

I'm current setting up Debezium connected to Amazon RDS for Postgres. I did have some issue with WAL consuming huge amount of disk space.

After some research, I've set up additional heartbeat config for debezium source connector, here my configuration

```json
{
        "database.server.name": "database-source-1",
        "heartbeat.interval.ms": "300000",
        "heartbeat.action.query": "SELECT pg_logical_emit_message(false, 'heartbeat', now()::varchar);"
}
```

This solved my issue with WAL consuming disk space, the configuration add a heartbeat event which emit every 5 minutes, there also a message produced to 2 kafka topics every 5 minutes as well. Those type of topics name is similar to this format:

- __debezium-heartbeat.database-source-1
- database-source-1.message

After a few days there a lot of messages produced in these type of topic, for now they didn't consume too much disk space, but I'm afraid after a while, more message will be produced and kafka will eat quite a lot of space, since I don't have any use for these topics (apart from checking emitted heartbeat event), is there any risk clearing messages in these type of topic after sometimes? I mainly use debezium to streaming data from postgres database to another postgres database and elasticsearch

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could try lowering the retention period of those topics, sure. But a simple heatbeat + timestamp string, every 5 seconds, stored for 7 days, by default, should not be that large of storage.

Comment: I haven't looked much into kafka configuration, is that mean by default after 7 days old heartbeat message will be clear right ? @OneCricketeer

Comment: All non compact topics lose data after a week, by default in Kafka, yes. Review retention.ms settings in your broker